# How to test Request objects' properties in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, http

I have a function that returns a `new Request` object;

```
import * as _url from 'url';

// pathname starts with '/content/'
const isContentUrl = (path) => /^\/content\//.test(path);

export default function(url) {
    let urlObj = _url.parse(url);

    if (isContentUrl(urlObj.pathname)) {
        urlObj.pathname = `/offline${urlObj.pathname}`;
    }

    return new Request(_url.format(urlObj), {
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'x-requested-with': 'sw'
        }
    });
}
```

Now I'm writing unit tests for this function and although I know there isn't *actually* much that changes here but say for example the headers could change for whatever reason, how can I assert parts of the request object like the headers, credentials or the URL?

Is there a nice way to be able to parse it for testing?

Ideally I'd like to do something like

```
it('should return a Request object with the correct headers', () => {
  const url = '/content/2c509c50-e4ba-11e6-9645-c9357a75844a';
  const request = offlineContent(url);

  const result = request.headers;
  const expected = {'x-requested-with': 'sw'};

  expect(result).to.eql(expected);
});
```

in my test

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that request here the [request](https://github.com/request/request) HTTP client, the returned object is an instance of the Request constructor defined [here](https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/request.js#L94).

If you follow through the code, you will see that headers provided are available simply through an [object member](https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/request.js#L150) and thus headers, and other members being attached to `self` can be easily introspected through javascript.

In addition, the http module through which requests are dispatched is available as [`self.httpModule`](https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/request.js#L456) and can be mocked by an implementation that is compliant with [node http module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) and requests dispatched through the library can be intercepted through [spies](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-spies/).

Comment: It is a Request object from the fetch API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request

Comment: Ah, that page already mentions all the methods you can use to inspect various aspects of the request eg. you can use Request.headers to get the headers of the request etc. You fetch a specific headers like this: `request.headers.getAll('x-requested-with')`. For getting all headers `request.headers.values()` gives you an iterator.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if there was a nicer way, I'll have to go with that

Answer (score 0):

MDN details the methods on the [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) and [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) object. Unfortunately I haven't found a way to convert this to an object that I could assert with a deep equal. But I can use these to assert against.

```
request.url;
request.credentials;
request.headers.get('x-requested-with');
```

Unfortunately the `Headers.getAll()` method has been deprecated so in order to fail tests if someone added a new header I have asserted against;

```
Array.from(request.headers.keys()).length
```